# How do I check if device needs SafeArea? (needs bottom/top padding)

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way that I can check if the device that is running the app needs a SafeArea. I need to run code based on this true or false value. I do NOT need to use the SafeArea widget. All I need is the true or false answer if the device needs a padding.

eg. Devices like iPhone 8 does not need padding, will not have padding even if Widget is wrapped in SafeArea widget.

eg. Devices like iPhone X does need padding and will have padding if the Widget is wrapped in a SafeArea.

How does the SafeArea widget tell if the device needs padding or not? I looked into the SafeArea widget code and was not able to understand what happens to tell it if the device needs padding or not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can check if the top and bottom padding > 0 to see if the user's device has a notch to it:

```
window.viewPadding
```

Here's an example of iPhone 11 Pro Max:

[image: Here's an example of iPhone 11 Pro Max]

Comment: This helped me achieve what I needed. I double checked on multiple devices, with and without SafeArea needs. Thanks.

Comment: Note: this is much different than MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding. 
for me the MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding was not producing anything, however this did. Once again Thanks.

Comment: This is the best way to handle bottom space for iOS devices. Thanks

Comment: @punjabi4life are you using window.viewPadding inside your custom appbar?

Comment: This works for iOS, but it doesn't seem to work on Android.

Comment: Note that `window.viewPadding` is in _physical_ pixels not in logical pixels (which are normally used in Flutter). You can divide it by `window.devicePixelRatio` to get logical pixels.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `MediaQuery` and get the `viewPadding` from that.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding
```

Comment: This should be the corrected answer for Flutter

Answer (score 4):

The best way to predict `SafeArea()` is required or not can be concluded based on whether you have used `Scaffold()` widget or not.

Let say, if you have not used Scaffold widget in your page or route then you should wrap it inside `SafeArea()` otherwise it will also consider your basel part or status bar or notch as your body of the screen.

Also, if you have used `Scaffold()`, but you didn't included appbar inside it then you must wrap your body inside SafeArea() to make sure that the screen is not considering statusbar or basel or notch as a safe part of the screen.

Comment: `SliverAppBar` works same as `AppBar` too. Summary, doesn't need `SafeArea` if `AppBar` was there.