# Flutter: detect if device has "back navigation" built into the OS?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I would like to know if the device has any functionality built into the OS for navigating back. Or in other words, if the user can trigger navigation without having an actual button within the app.

For example, an iPhone 7 does not have a physical back button or a swipe-back gesture. If the app doesn't have it's own way to navigate, the user can get stuck.

On the contrary, most modern devices have some way of going back built into the system, like a physical/virtual back button or a swipe-back gesture.

Can I distinguish between these types of devices?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen it is only IOS that do this, so it can be done with:

```
 if (Platform.isIOS){
#show backButton();
}
```

But I have not seen a package or function that specifically lets you know this information. Keep me in the loop if you find anything

Comment: You just gave me an idea. A possible solution would be to check if the device is iOS and has a bottom-notch, in which case it's definitely a newer iPhone with gesture navigation. Checking for a bottom notch is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848681/how-do-i-check-if-device-needs-safearea-needs-bottom-top-padding

But it's still not an elegant solution.